# Windows updates on Sharepoint Servers in the same farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching, windows, hotfix

We have a SharePoint farm with few servers. Recently some servers are updated with Windows security patch & few are not updated. I am aware that Sharepoint product patch level should be same on a farm, but do we need to consider the Windows updates as well to be same on all servers in the farm?

Answer (score 4):

**First,** you should be aware of the `SharePoint Security Fixes` that included within the `Windows Update` **will not be reflected** until running `the SharePoint Configuration Wizard`

**Second**, It's recommended to don't include the `SharePoint Security Fixes` with the windows update to avoid your current confusion.

However, if you will install the `SharePoint Security Fixes` with the `Windows Update` it will require installing the same `Windows Update` on all others servers plus you must schedule a time to run the  `the SharePoint Configuration Wizard` on all SharePoint servers to reflect these Security Fixes.

> **Note:** Running SharePoint Configuration Wizard will require downtime.

In case you don't installed the Windows Update on other servers, it will not affect the farm until running the SharePoint Configuration Wizard, and in this case, the other servers that not have windows update installed will raise

- `Upgrade require` warning in `Manage Servers in the Farm`.
- Also, you will get a [Product/patch installation or server upgrade required](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/11/21/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/) health analyzer warning.

---

**What you should do now?**

It's up to you to do one of the following options

1. Perform a Windows Update on other SharePoint Servers, then run the SharePoint Configuration wizard on all SharePoint Servers cross the farm to reflect the installed SharePoint Security fixes. `(But in the next time, as I told you the SharePoint security fixes should not be included within the windows update)`
2. Don't run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard and don't install the windows update on other servers. and wait for your next patch schedule to patch your farm with a CU or Service Pack.

> **Note:** `The Cumulative Update full package` will include all previous fix updates whatever it's a security update or functional
>   update between the previous service pack and the current CU.

So it will include the security fixes that you have installed with the Windows Update on the first server.

---

**Also, you should take care about the following important points before applying a new CU:**

- Don't forget to get a farm backup before applying CU, (you can't do CU rollback)
- Before applying the CU on production, you should apply it first on test farm.
- It's preferred to install the CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm.

Check also [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)