# Are there any mandatory packs/patches to SP2013?

Tags: service-pack

Our SP2013 enviroment is in SP1. I understand its good to keep the environment updated with the latest service packs/patches but due to business requirements we don't do it regularly. Just want to understand if there has been any mandatory service packs/security patches for SP2013 post SP1?

Answer (score 3):

Since SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1, **there is no** any public or mandatory update. Check the full list at [SharePoint Server 2013 build numbers](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sharepoint/#2013)

But there's a CU that depend on old CU, don't worry you will find the pre request instructions at the CU download page.

**Recommended Points.**

- Although the periodic patching is useful, it's recommended to install a new CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm. you can find the issue fixes also at the download page at "Known issue" section.
- It's not recommended to install the latest CU of the current month. if you need to install the latest CU try the current month -1 or -2
- Installing CU will require downtime.
- Read also [Windows updates on Sharepoint Servers in the same farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223734/windows-updates-on-sharepoint-servers-in-the-same-farm/223735#223735)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing post-SP1 has been mandatory for support purposes. If you open a support case, Microsoft will likely ask that you update to the latest CU. In addition, there have been a significant number of post-SP1 security patches that you should consider; that said at this point I would just install the latest CU as managing that many security patches would be difficult.

Comment: Does the latest CU contains all the security patches till date?

Comment: Yes it does contain them

Comment: Thanks for all the info.Will plan to update the environment with the latest CU.